# Pass a referance to API Gateway to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using the Serverless framework and one of my lambda functions needs to know the API gateway id. I tried setting an envierment varable like the following.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs6.10
    Environment:
      Variables:
        API_GATEWAY: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi

Resources:
  Test:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: LeadLambda.test
      CodeUri: ./Lead
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /
            Method: get
```

But when I try and deploy I get a circular dependency error.

```
Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Circular dependency between resources: [TestGetResourcePermissionProd, ServerlessRestApi, Test, TestGetResourcePermissionTest, ServerlessRestApiDeploymentb5240aa4ca, ServerlessRestApiProdStage]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was to hard code the integration uri in the API instead of referencing the Lambda.

```
Globals:
  Function:
    Runtime: nodejs6.10
    Environment:
        Variables:
          API: !Sub https://${Api}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/prod

Resources:
  Entry:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: prompt-stack-Entry
      Handler: LeadLambda.entry
      CodeUri: s3://ddg-prompt/LeadLambda.zip
      Role: !GetAtt LeadRole.Arn
      Events:
        GetResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /lead
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: !Ref Api

  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        paths:
          /lead:
            post:
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Successful operation
                  responseTemplates:
                    application/json: ""
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:prompt-stack-Entry/invocations
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: '200'
                    responseTemplates:
                      application/json: ''
```

Comment: this approach does not work, ref the api gateway from lambda env variable and event, cause circular dependency error...